# rename maven jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

My plugin section in the pom file looks like this:

```
  <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>

          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.gateway.gatewayService</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

After the build finishes, I'm left with the following files:

```
gateway-1.1.0.pom
gateway-1.1.0.jar
gateway-1.1.0.jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I would like to get the following outcome instead:

```
gateway-1.1.0.pom
gateway-1.1.0.jar
gateway-1.1.0-all.jar
```

Which means changing `gateway-1.1.0.jar-with-dependencies.jar` to `gateway-1.1.0-all.jar`, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the content

```
<descriptorRefs>
  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

Of line 5,6&7 and then try.

Comment: `Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two tags which are `<finalName>` and `<appendAssemblyId>` inside `<configuration>`

Set `<appendAssemblyId>` to `false`

You need to change your `maven-assembly-plugin` as below

```
 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>

          <finalName>all</finalName>   // name of your jar
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>  // append will be false

          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>

          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.gateway.gatewayService</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```